# Calling Url.Action in JQuery with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm trying to use Url.Action to call the controller c# function:

```
public ActionResult Setup(string ID, string Definition)
```

This function is located in the controller class MachineController.cs, and it returns a PartialView.

So, in with my script, i'm trying to call function 'Setup' with the line:

```
var selected = $('#dropselector').find(':selected').text();

$.get('@Url.Action("Setup", "Machine", new { ID = @Model.ID , Definition = "_holder"})'.replace("_holder", selected), function (data) {
     $('#MachineSetup').replaceWith(data);
});
```

What seems to happen is the first parameter (ID) is passed no problem, but the second parameter (Definition) is always empty string. I've even tried assigning 'Definition' to @Model.ID same as the ID field as they are both strings, but it just seems to result in the same, ID is populated but Definition is an empty string.

The problem definitely relates to the passing of a second parameter, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to watch the `selected` variable in the debugger's tools of your browser (F12)?

Comment: I think there is syntax error near replace("_holder", selected), , .... Remove extra comma.

Comment: Yes sorry, second comma was a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try the following

```
var selected = $('#dropselector').find(':selected').text();

$.get(
   '@Url.Action("Setup","Machine", new { ID = @Model.ID })',
   {
     data:{definition:selected}
   } , 
   function (data) 
   {
       $('#MachineSetup').replaceWith(data);
   });
```

as the url will contain the `Model.ID` but the dynamic value of selected will change.

also if you are doing a `Setup` would you not consider a `POST` action to make sure the values are not cached on the client machine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've discovered if I use this format (adding both parameters to the data field) and use $.ajax (rather than 'get' or 'post') it works! Thanks!